# Exception thrown while constructing Processor object Invalid index

Tags: java, compiler-errors, aix

I'm getting an error while compiling my java source in AIX server with encoding set to IBM-1047. Below is the error,

> [INFO ] 2018-04-17 09:21:13,272 [main] - compilation output messageerror: Exception thrown while constructing Processor object: Invalid index
>
> [FATAL] 2018-04-17 09:21:13,273 [main] - error: Exception thrown while constructing Processor object: Invalid index

If i remove the encoding variable and compile with the default encoding as ISO-8859-1, im getting the below error,

> [ERROR] 2018-04-17 09:23:30,030 [main] - File COPY.USER.N.SIGNON, line 1:1
>
> [ERROR] 2018-04-17 09:23:30,030 [main] -   unexpected token: &
>
> [ERROR] 2018-04-17 09:23:30,031 [main] - File COPY.USER.N.SIGNON, line 1:2
>
> [ERROR] 2018-04-17 09:23:30,031 [main] -   unexpected char: 0xEA

Please can anyone advise me about the issue and help with the resolution.

Comment: IBM-1047 -- is it a sort of EBCDIC? (I did find IBM-1046 with google)

Comment: Hi Zsigmond, Yes it is EBCDIC IBM-1047

Comment: As a start, try these commands (though they didn't really work for me) `javac -encoding Cp1047 myebcdicprogram.java` and `javac -encoding Cp037 myebcdicprogram.java`

Answer (score 0):

Made some experiments with `javac -encoding IBM037` and `javac -encoding IBM1047`. The former seems working, the latter not so much. Here's a workaround that might help:

```
mv ebcdic.java ebcdic_1047.java
tr '\260\137\272\273\255\275' '\137\260\255\275\272\273' <ebcdic_1047.java >ebcdic.java
javac -encoding IBM037 ebcdic.java
```

Sources:

```
ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/globalization/gcoc/attachments/CP00037.txt
ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/globalization/gcoc/attachments/CP00037.pdf
ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/globalization/gcoc/attachments/CP01047.txt
ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/globalization/gcoc/attachments/CP01047.pdf
```

Comment: On second thought, it might be not AIX. Also it might be not Java. For all we know, it might be Cobol on some IBM mainframe.